# VBA macro run time error '5' on excel in a Sub

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a slight issue with my VBA macro I get a run time error on this part and I can't figure out where it is, basically the code is meant to open a File Explorer and the user chooses a CSV and then the VBA copies the sheet in a new sheet inside the workbook that has the Macro in it.

```
Sub manipulate_csv()
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    csvDatasheetName = "CSV Feed Data"
    massagedDatasheetName = "Massaged Data"
    objFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files(* . *) , * . * ") ' choose load path'
    connectionText = "TEXT;" & objFile
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        connectionText, Destination:= _
        Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "TestCSV"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End with
End sub
```

If you have any idea what is causing my issue, I would be very thankful, to help me solve it.
Best regards

Comment: Try stepping through your code line by line in the VBE (F8) and see which line the error is thrown on.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Thanks i just did so, this issue comes from the line : 'objFile = Application.GetOpenFilename'

Comment: I'm having a look into a few things now I suspect it may be... in the meantime, do you get a returned result or error if you type `?Application.GetOpenFilename` in the immediate pane and choose you file?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is it may be a character limit being hit perhaps? How long is your file path?

Comment: @SamuelEverson around 25 characters long.

Comment: `"All Files (*.*),*.*"` without those extra spaces.  Also where/how is `objFile` declared?

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried this, for  `objFile` it's just used at the begining no other declaration is done

Comment: What is the text of the error message?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line as posted: even with the extra spaces in the filter pattern.